# How to find the value of this Boolean in this chess program?

Tags: java, inheritance, chess

I have this SchachChecker.java file, which basically reads in a certain configuration of pieces on a chessboard.

My goal is to implement a function (moeglicheZuege) in Schachbrett.java that prints out all the possible moves a player can make on this turn, which will be called by the SchachChecker class.

My approach is to iterate through all the squares, check which piece is on it and from which player (black or white) and then check, what moves this piece could perform.

So far I've been able to do the iteration and to figure out, which piece is sitting on each square but I just can't figure out the color of the pieces.

SchachChecker.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class SchachChecker {
  public static final Map<Character, Class<? extends Schachbrett.Feld>> pieceMap =
      new HashMap<Character, Class<? extends Schachbrett.Feld>>() {
        {
          put('b', Schachbrett.Bauer.class);
          put('s', Schachbrett.Springer.class);
          put('l', Schachbrett.Laeufer.class);
          put('t', Schachbrett.Turm.class);
          put('d', Schachbrett.Dame.class);
          put('k', Schachbrett.Koenig.class);
          put(' ', Schachbrett.Feld.class);
        }
      };

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Parameter fehlt: Schachbrett");
    } else if (args.length < 2) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Parameter fehlt: wer ist am Zug?");
    }
    final boolean whiteToMove = "w".equals(args[1]);
    if (!(whiteToMove || "s".equals(args[1]))) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unbekannte Farbe: '" + args[1] + "'");
    }
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(
        Paths.get(args[0]), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    final Schachbrett board = new Schachbrett();
    for (int lineIndex = 8; lineIndex >= 1; lineIndex--) {
      // Lines are enumerated from bottom to top, that's why the first
      // read line is the one with number 8.
      final String line = reader.readLine();
      if (line == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Zu wenig Zeilen!");
      }
      for (char column = 'a'; column <= 'h'; column++) {
        final char cur =
            column - 'a' >= line.length() ? ' ' : line.charAt(column - 'a');
        final Class<? extends Schachbrett.Feld> pieceClass =
            pieceMap.get(Character.toLowerCase(cur));
        if (pieceClass == null) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Nicht erlaubtes Zeichen: '" + cur + "''");
        }
        Schachbrett.Feld f;
        if (cur == ' ') {
          // leeres Feld ist nicht schwarz oder weiÃŸ
          f = pieceClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } else {
          f = pieceClass.getConstructor(
              Boolean.TYPE).newInstance(Character.isUpperCase(cur));
          System.out.println(f);
        }
        board.setFeld(lineIndex, column, f);
      }
    }
    reader.close();
    Set<Schachbrett.Zug> zugSet = board.moeglicheZuege(whiteToMove);
    Schachbrett.Zug[] zuege = zugSet.toArray(new Schachbrett.Zug[zugSet.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(zuege);
    for (final Schachbrett.Zug zug: zuege) {
      System.out.println(zug.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Schachbrett.java:

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Schachbrett {
  /**
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Variable part: Classes for the pieces on the squares.
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *
   * Note: The constructors must be preserved.
   */

  public static class Feld {}

  /**
   * A square, on which a piece is placed.
   * The piece is either black or white.
   */
  public static abstract class Figur extends Feld {
    final boolean white;
    protected Figur(boolean white) { this.white = white; }

    public boolean isWhite() { return white; }

    public char id() {
      return getClass().getSimpleName().charAt(0);
    }
  }

  public static final class Bauer extends Figur {
    public Bauer(boolean white) { super(white); }
  }

  public static final class Laeufer extends Figur {
    public Laeufer(boolean white) { super(white); }
  }

  public static final class Springer extends Figur {
    public Springer(boolean white) { super(white); }
  }

  public static final class Turm extends Figur {
    public Turm(boolean white) { super(white); }
  }

  public static final class Dame extends Figur {
    public Dame(boolean white) { super(white); }
  }

  public static final class Koenig extends Figur {
    public Koenig(boolean white) { super(white); }
  }

  /**
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * End variable part: Classes for the pieces on the squares.
   * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  /**
   * Array, that holds all squares of the chessboard. Access results
   * with getFeld(line, column), see below.
   */
  private final Feld[] felder = new Feld[64];

  /**
   * Initialization: all squares empty.
   */
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
      felder[i] = new Feld();
    }
  }

  private static int feldIndex(int line, char column) {
    return (line - 1) * 8 + ((int) column - (int) 'a');
  }

  public Feld getFeld(int line, char column) {
    return felder[feldIndex(line, column)];
  }

  public void setFeld(int line, char column, Feld value) {
    felder[feldIndex(line, column)] = value;
  }

  /**
   * A move of the piece FigurId from square (lineFrom, columnFrom) to square
   * (lineTo, columnTo)
   */
  public final class Zug implements Comparable<Zug> {
    public int lineFrom, lineTo;
    public char columnFrom, columnTo;
    public char pieceId;

    public Zug (int lineFrom, char columnFrom, int lineTo, char columnTo,
                char pieceId) {
      this.lineFrom = lineFrom; this.columnFrom = columnFrom;
      this.lineTo = lineTo; this.columnTo = columnTo;
      this.pieceId = pieceId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return new StringBuilder().append(pieceId).append(columnFrom).append(
          Integer.toString(lineFrom)).append('-').append(columnTo).append(
          Integer.toString(lineTo)).toString();
    }

    // required methods for sorting during the output
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      final int fromIndex = feldIndex(lineFrom, columnFrom);
      final int toIndex = feldIndex(lineTo, columnTo);
      int pieceIndex;
      switch(Character.toUpperCase(this.pieceId)) {
        case 'B': pieceIndex = 0; break;
        case 'S': pieceIndex = 1; break;
        case 'L': pieceIndex = 2; break;
        case 'T': pieceIndex = 3; break;
        case 'D': pieceIndex = 4; break;
        case 'K': pieceIndex = 5; break;
        default: throw new RuntimeException("Can never happen");
      }
      if (Character.isUpperCase(pieceIndex)) {
        pieceIndex = pieceIndex + 6;
      }
      // perfect hash (squareindex is at most 63 == 2^6 - 1)
      return toIndex + (fromIndex << 6) + (pieceIndex << 12);
    }

    public int compareTo(final Zug other) {
      return hashCode() - other.hashCode();
    }
  }

  public Set<Zug> moeglicheZuege(boolean whiteToMove) {
    /*
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Variable part: algorithm
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
     return Collections.<Zug>emptySet();
     // End
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: FYI : You should not mix language, not even talking about comments, in the variable name or exception messages.

Comment: And your color is simply in `Figur.white`. So what is the problem about figuring it out ? EDIT : by the way, a chess piece is not a cell on the board, so `Figur` should not extends `Feld`, `Feld` should have a `Figur` variable, meaning it could hold a piece (or not if `null`). Just a OO mistake here.

Comment: Yes, but when iterating through the squares I'm not finding the pieces on them. There is no getFigur() to find a piece on a given square.

Comment: Where are you iterating in all this, `moeglicheZuege` is almost empty... provide a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

looks like a piece of computer science  homework ....
but its all there

```
 public boolean isWhite() { return white; }
```

so if I understand your question and you want to know the representation of black & white ... white is true and black is false

Answer (score 0):

> There is no getFigur() to find a piece on a given square.

Because your square is a `Feld`, this is confirmed by

```
/**
 * Array, that holds all squares of the chessboard. Access results
 * with getFeld(line, column), see below.
 */
private final Feld[] felder = new Feld[64];
```

That class is currently the super class of every piece.

```
 public static abstract class Figur extends Feld {
```

This is where you have made your mistake about the relation between those two entities.

- A `Piece` is not a `Square`,
- A `Piece` is holded by a `Square`.

So you need to update your relations to match those statements.

```
public class Feld{
    private Figur figur;

    public Figur getFigur(){ return figur;}
}
```

*Having an empty class like your had with `Feld` is generally a clue that there is a problem.*

And then the piece should not extends the square

```
public class Figur {
final boolean white;
    protected Figur(boolean white) { this.white = white; }

    public boolean isWhite() { return white; }
    ...
}
```

From there, you will be able to iterate your board, and get the figur on it (or not)